# SOLVED:Error saying: wordA is not defined, when I inject the files dynamically to DOM which contains wordA variable

Tags: javascript, variables

```
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

let allAlphabet = ['A', 'B'];

allAlphabet.forEach(item =>{

  // injecting script data file which contains variables wordA, wordB
  domElement("#injectData").innerHTML += `<script src="data/D${item}.js">`;


  // it says wordA is not defined
  // (but this variables are defined in the files which I injected to DOM using the code above)
  // but if I manually add those script tag to the dom without injecting by js then it works well
  console.log(eval(`word${item}`)); // dynamic variable     

});
```

why this don't work when I inject those script tag dynamically

anyone please try to understand the problem

if someone have some time to view the full code then I will put the link of full code

Comment: Scripts added through `innerHTML` are not executed, you have to create the script element directly (`document.createElement()`) and add that to the dom. Note it also won't be loaded immediatly so even if your code was injecting the script right they wouldnt have loaded by the time your log code ran

Comment: I am really grateful to you for your help. Your suggestion solves my problem. So many thanks...

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it. Do not edit the title to add "Solved",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts added through innerHTML are not executed, you have to create the script element directly (document.createElement()) and add that to the dom. Note it also won't be loaded immediatly so even if your code was injecting the script right they wouldnt have loaded by the time your log code ran – Patrick Evans